# replacing single quote and other symbols with blank space

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace symbols using javascript regex function. I couldnt find out a way to replace single quotes. 
The code that I used is `.replace(/([.?*&+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "");`

How Do I add singlee quote escape in to this one??

Answer (score 0):

Add `'` to the beginning of the bracket expression:

```
.replace(/(['.?*&+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `'` at the end of the character class and it will be removed. It throws an error because of the dash `-`. It tries to define a range (you **can** do `[A-Z]` but of course `|-'` would not make sense). So your final regex: `.replace(/([.?*&+^$[\]\\(){}|\-'])/g, "");`
Is escapes the dash to make it a literal dash and not a range character.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create proper regular expression by escaping any character you want to replace. This way you can add any character to this list without any trouble.

That would give simple command like :

```
.replace(/([\.\?\*\&\+\^\$\[\]\\\(\)\{\}\|\-\'])/g, "")
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to reverse the expression, and highlight everything that's not a valid character.

```
string.replace(/([^a-zA-Z0-9])/, '');
```

Adding a ^ to the start of the character map inverts the character class. So this will remove any non alphanumeric character.

Comment: did you test it? it would be good if we could generalize the answer like the u gave.. but it is not working..